# merge raster images: error message procedure not found

Tags: qgis, gdal, error, merge

I am using QGIS 1.8.0. Whenever I try to merge raster images I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "C:\PROGRA~1\Quantum GIS Lisboa\bin\gdal_merge.py", line 36, in 
import gdal 
File "C:\PROGRA~1\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\gdal.py", line 2, in 
from osgeo.gdal import deprecation_warn 
File "C:\PROGRA~1\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\osgeo\__init__.py", line 21, in 
_gdal = swig_import_helper() 
File "C:\PROGRA~1\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\osgeo\__init__.py", line 17, in swig_import_helper 
_mod = imp.load_module('_gdal', fp, pathname, description) 
ImportError: DLL load failed: Die angegebene Prozedur wurde nicht gefunden.
```

Does anyone know what I sould do?

Comment: If you click on the 'Log Messages' icon, extreme bottom-right of the QGIS screen, does it tell you that Python support is enabled?

Comment: Hello, Yes it does.

Answer (score 3):

In the past I've had this problem too. It seemed to come and go with different versions of QGIS and I never found a reason for this.

You can work around the problem by making a virtual raster from your raster images. Raster -> Miscellaneous -> Build Virtual Raster (Catalog). This will build a *.vrt file that you can treat exactly as if it was a merged raster.

Added later: I should have mentioned that it should now be possible to convert the *.vrt file to a GeoTIFF (or any other permitted format) using "Translate" from under the "Raster" menu.

Nick.

Comment: Hi Nick, thanks for the adise. Just unfortunatelly I get another error message trying this: ERROR 1: Failed to write .vrt file in FlushCache()

Comment: Greetings Vanessa, over time I've had several instances of problems with merging rasters, but never problems with creating VRTs. I think it would be a good idea to take this issue to the mailing list. N.

Comment: Hey, now it works! Thank you very much for your help!